# Conditionally format groups of rows in a table

Tags: excel

I have a table in which column B specifies a group for each row, and want to conditionally format (CF) every other **group** of rows. I have tried [these](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ContentBanding.aspx) [solutions](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/an-excel-conditional-format-that-expands-with-grouped-data/), but the CF rule goes awry when I insert a new row; they only appear to work with a normal range of cells.

Prefixing a number to each group, I can use `=ISEVEN(LEFT($B1, FIND("-", $B1)-1))` to achieve what I want while keeping the rule intact when I insert a new row.

I have the groups listed in a separate table `$W$3:$W$9` for another purpose. Perhaps using something along the lines of `=MOD(ROW($W$3:$W$9),2)`, how can I devise a CF rule that:

1. works with a table without having to prefix a number to each group;
2. does not go awry when I insert a new row;
3. does not require a helper column?

Comment: If your data are in a table alternative rows can be highlighted simply by checking the "Banded Rows" Table Style Option in the Table Tools Design menu. It would seem there is no need for CF beyond that.

Comment: **Groups** <> alternative rows.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. A CF solution would only seem possible if each row can be connected to a group, for example by having its ID in column B. A VBA solution should be possible if beginning and end of each group can be identified, for example by having a caption in column A to identify its first row with subsequent rows either blank or repetitive.